# Wordpress/Php Nested loops

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to nest a loop, basically if the post has a thumbnail then it should show a div, if not then it should do nothing.

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() );?>

                <div class="featured-image-row">

                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

However, this gives me a nasty unexpected T_ENDIF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed : after second if statement

Change

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() );?>
```

To

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
```

Comment: Great, thanks, really shows my rusty PHP knowledge. Another point to the question, is this nested loop efficient? i tried if (have_posts()) && ( has_post_thumbnail() ) but it really didn't like that. I assume it doesnt know if the post ha a thumbnail until the first loop has ran? EDIT  why the downvote? :(

Comment: @user319940 i didn't downvoted your question. and in your second question your are right. need to run have_post() first

Comment: Sorry, why the downvote was a more general thing :P. And thought so about the loop, thanks for your help.